# How to execute a process remotely using python

Tags: python, ssh

I want to connect to and execute a process on a remote server using Python.  I want to be able to get the return code and stderr (if any) of the process.  Has anyone ever done anything like this before.  I have done it with ssh, but I want to do it from Python script.

Cheers.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536370/execute-arbitrary-python-code-remotely-can-it-be-done

Comment: Example: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/looper/ This is Microsoft-licensed opensource due to an acquisition.  It works well on Linux.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, you can call ssh from python...

```
import subprocess
ret = subprocess.call(["ssh", "user@host", "program"]);

# or, with stderr:
prog = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "user@host", "program"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
errdata = prog.communicate()[1]
```

Comment: You'll need to make sure that you have key-based authentication to the remote host, and the proper keys.  Otherwise, you'll be prompted for a password.

Comment: nice, apparently I'm out of date - was going to recommend os.spawnlp, but i see the subprocess module was introduced to replace it.

Comment: Thanks dude.  When you exec a command over ssh the return code and stderr is that of the exec'd command, if ssh doesn't have any issues itself.  I can the popen class and the communicate() method to tap into it from there.

Comment: Use the [ssh module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.11) instead of calling `subprocess`. Even at the time this answer was posted the former version of the ssh module (called Paramiko) existed.

Comment: Better to use Fabric or paramiko as detailed in the following answers.  Fabric is higher level interface than paramiko.

Answer (score 43):

Use the [ssh module called paramiko](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/) which was created for this purpose instead of using `subprocess`. Here's an example below:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect("hostname", username="user")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('program')
print "stderr: ", stderr.readlines()
print "pwd: ", stdout.readlines()
```

UPDATE: The example used to use the `ssh` module, but that is now deprecated and [paramiko](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/) is the up-to-date module that provides ssh functionality in python.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe if you want to wrap the nuts and bolts of the ssh calls you could use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org)
This library is geared towards deployment and server management, but it could also be useful for these kind of problems.

Also have a look at [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html). This implements a task queue for Python/Django on various brokers. Maybe an overkill for your problem, but if you are going to call more functions on multiple machines it will save you a lot of headache managing your connections.