# import ssh not found in Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my Python27 library there is no ssh.py file. In PyScripter therefore I am seeing this error:

```
>>> import ssh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ssh
```

What is the work around ?

Thanks,
Amitra

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/946962/3270800

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to connect to a Unix server from my Windows 7 machine. So, I am trying to create a Python script which will help me to automatically login to the Unix server.

In my Windows laptop I have installed Python 3.0. PIP is already in python 3.0. So, I did

"pip install ssh" from windows command prompt and it asked to install Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0. I installed VC++ from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266

and ran "pip install ssh" again. This time, it ended with "Successfully installed Pycrypto, Cleaning Up..."

I opened PyScripter 3.0 again and found I could run import ssh.

Thank you for your support.

Regards,
Amitra