# write python code in one computer and running it on another automatically

Tags: python

I have the following situation.
I want to write python code in my Laptop that will take more than 24 hours to run.I am using UBUNTU 12.04 lts.

Is it possible so that I write python code in my laptop, automatically send it to some remote desktop, run there and send the output result to my laptop when done?
  one way suggested to me is to use **openssh**.

But I want to do this in the following way----

1. Write and Debug Python Code in my laptop.(Solved)
2. email the code as attachment to **********@gmail.com(Solved)
3. **Other python program in the desktop will automatically download** and run the source code(Unsolved)
4. and email the output file back to my gmail id.(Solved)

what is the **python code to download the attachment from the latest email from a specific gmail folder?**

Comment: If you're application/simulation takes over 24 hours a compiled language might be a better choice than python.

Comment: It might not Be because of the massiveness of the programm, for all we know he is collecting data over a 24 hour timespan. Which exactly points out what is wrong with this question btw... see [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also have a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/536370/1025391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your remote system is windows, a good option would be to use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from SysInternals.

Ex. If your script is long_running.py a typical usage would be

```
PsExec \\remote-server -c long_running.py
```

If your remote system is *nix, and your local system is Windows, you can use ssh for remote execution via Plink (part of PuTTY).

```
plink remote-server@user -m long_running.py
```

Finally if both remote and local machine are *nix systems, you can simply use `ssh`

```
ssh remote-server@user 'bash -s' < long_running.py
```

**Note** This is just some possible options, but the idea is remote execution is possible either via `ssh` or a similar option (like PsExec) for Windows

Answer (score 0):

If both systems are running *nix, you can easily do all your dev work and debugging locally, while still executing remotely:

One time set up:

1. [Mount a folder from the remote box locally](http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-mount-remote-directory-over-ssh-on-linux.html)
2. On your laptop, save your project/script to that (now local) folder, or set the mounted folder as your project's save path in your IDE.

Publishing:

1. Do work
2. Click the save button

Executing:

1. SSH into the remote box and open a new [screen](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)
2. Navigate to the folder you'd previously mounted, and run your script.
3. You can then safely detach and close ssh if necessary (ctrl+a d), and re-attach later:
   3a. screen -ls (to find the screen name)
   3b. screen -x screen_name

The advantage of this solution is that if you've got an ongoing project requiring frequent edits/changes, you can do all your dev work/debugging locally, and the only work required to "publish" is clicking the save button, starting the screen, and running.